# MySQL: Count certain values

Tags: mysql, count

SELECT
        reporting.station
    FROM
        reporting
    LEFT JOIN
        channel
    ON
        MD5(igmpurl)=reporting.station
    WHERE
        reporting.station!="n/a"
    ORDER BY
        name;

resulting in this table:

[image: Query like it is]

Now I'd like to count the number of each element, which should something look like:

[image: Result like I'd would like to have it]

**Note**: I know about `COUNT(station)` which would return the number of the rows (20) but is **not** what I want.

Any idea how to solve this in MySQL (InnoDB)?
Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    reporting.station, COUNT(reporting.station)
FROM
    reporting
LEFT JOIN
    channel
ON
    MD5(igmpurl)=reporting.station
WHERE
    reporting.station!="n/a"
GROUP BY reporting.station
ORDER BY
    name;
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`:

In your case, it should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    reporting.station,
    COUNT(*) AS rep_station_count
FROM
    reporting
LEFT JOIN
    channel
ON
    MD5(igmpurl)=reporting.station
WHERE
    reporting.station!="n/a"
GROUP BY
    reporting.station
ORDER BY
    name;
```

Note that allowing normal and [aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) columns (e.g. `AVG()`,`COUNT()` etc.) in the same query is MySQL specific.

Comment: (also, I'm not quite sure what you need the `ORDER BY` for, but that's not directly related to your question)

Comment: Thanks to you too. I'll give Headshota the accept because he was 2 minutes faster :P (and he needs the reputation more than you do :P) `ORDER BY` isn't that important. May I somehow get the row with the highest count? Or is the easiest way to `ORDER BY` the count and take the first?

Comment: @Atmocreations: For getting the highest count, you're on the right track: in this case, it would be `ORDER BY rep_station_count DESC` - first row is the one you want. Easiest and probably fastest, too :)